# How to call Windows COM object like Excel.Application from node.js with electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, com, electron, office-interop

How to call Windows COM object like Excel.Application and Outlook from node.js with electron?

I find the [win32ole](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32ole) but it is 5 years old. I am using Office 2016.

It seems like the [electron-edge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-edge-js) or [edge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edge-js) can do the job but do you have any example?

Comment: What's wrong with win32ole being 5 years old? COM is 25+ years old, and the fundamentals haven't significantly changed in a long time.

Comment: Is win32ole supports macOS also, because the electron is a hybrid/cross-platform app ?